# Sort a Map based on size

Tags: java

I have a map like so:

```
Map<List<Item>, Double> items = new HashMap<List<Item>, Double>();
```

I would like to sort this hashmap based on the size of the `List<Item>` where the largest sized ones are first. I don't care about the ordering within same sized objects though.

So far I've tried to use a `TreeSet` like so:

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>> sortedItems = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>(
     new Comparator<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(
            Entry<List<Item>, Double> o1,
            Entry<List<Item>, Double> o2) {
               return o2.getKey().size() - o1.getKey().size();
        }
    });
sortedItems.addAll(items.entrySet());
```

However, the `sortedItems` object is only taking one of every sized list. It is treating equally sized lists as duplicates and is ignoring them. How can I fix this issue.

EDIT: So from what I can tell, when 2 lists of the same size are being compared, my `compare` method is returning `0`. This tells the set that the entries are equal and they are treated as duplicates. So I guess the only way to fix this is to ensure that the compare method never returns `0`. So I wrote this code:

```
@Override
public int compare(
    Entry<List<AuctionItem>, Double> o1,
    Entry<List<AuctionItem>, Double> o2) {
        if (o1.getKey().size() <= o2.getKey().size()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your comparator needs to not return 0 then. Returning 0 means "these items are the same" and you can't have identical items in a map.

Comment: @immibis So what should I make it return? Can it be anything other than 0 or does it matter whether I return a positive or negative number

Comment: You need to decide how to sort them.

Comment: @immibis I'm sorry this is confusing. I just want to return them from biggest to smallest without the set ignoring duplicates. Is that you mean by needing to decide how to sort them?

Comment: I mean that if you have equal size lists A and B, then your comparator needs to decide whether A comes before B, or B comes before A. There is no "don't care" option.

Comment: Compile error, did you want to write: `sortedItems.addAll(items.entrySet());`?

Comment: @icza Yes I did, sorry about that I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to put an item into a `TreeSet` for which your custom `Comparator` returns `0`, the item **will not** be placed into the `Set`.

You have to use a `Comparator` which doesn't return `0`. For `List`s whose sizes are equal, you have to define a *consistent*, *arbitrary* order.

Here is an easy and convinient way to do so:

```
new Comparator<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<List<Item>, Double> o1,
                       Entry<List<Item>, Double> o2) {

        int diff = o2.getKey().size() - o1.getKey().size();
        return diff != 0 ? diff :
            System.identityHashCode(o2.getKey()) -
                System.identityHashCode(o1.getKey());
    }
};
```

Basically what I do is this: if the 2 lists have different size, `size2 - size1` will do. If they have the same size, I return the difference of their *identity hashcodes* which will always differ from `0` because the *identity hashcode* is the memory address which is different for distinct objects. And it is always the same for an object, so the comparator will always return the same order for 2 lists having the same size.

Using this comparator you will get a sorted set which allows lists having the same size, and it will be sorted by list size.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `TreeSet` with `Comparator`, and as per your implementation of the `compare()`, it returns 0 if the size of the list is same. As `TreeSet` cannot contain duplicates, it adds only one of those lists whose size is equal. You do not need to create a `TreeSet`in order to sort your `Map`, because **SETS** should be used when the elements resemble mathematical sets (NO duplicate elements). You could possibly do :

```
List<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>> list =
        new LinkedList<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>( map.entrySet() );

Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double> o1, Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getKey().size().compareTo( o2.getKey.size() );
            }
        } );
```

That is, put the entries of map in a List and then sort the list.

Comment: No, just no. You can't sort a map. A map doesn't have order. You need to put the entries into a list to be able to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you are using a list of values (items) as the key to your hashmap; however, I'll give it a go.

At the core any Map is not an ordered collection.  In short, if "Pete" has a height of 67 inches and "Bob" has a height of 72 inches, then without some extra bit of information, it is not possible to determine if Bob should come before or after Pete.

Ordered by "key" or in this case, "name" one might impose alphabetical ordering, in which case "Bob" comes before "Pete".

Ordered by "value" or in this case, "height" one might impose smallest to largest ordering, in which case "Pete" comes before "Bob".

I'm sure that you know what you want to order by (the size of the list), but this example means to illustrate that a Map alone is a poor data structure for ordering.  Even ordered maps in Java only sort by insertion order.

My suggestion is to keep two collections in the same wrapping class.  One that contains an ordered list of the keys, and another that contains the Map.  Walk the ordered list of keys and return the map values in that order if you want an ordered set of the values by their key characteristics.  It will be easier to understand, and much more readable.

Also realize that the Map is not listening to the key values, as such, if someone who has a key decides to add an entry to the List that the key maintains, the Map will not know of the alteration and will not recompute the bucket for the key's former value.  As such, to use a Map properly, you need to approach it in one of two ways.

1. Make the map keys immutable, copying the values upon input and returning `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` wrappers on output.
2. Accept Map keys that can be listened to, and make the map a subscriber to the key updates that might occur.  When the map detects a key change, the values are removed from the old key location and re-added back to the map with the new key.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need constant sorting over time, you can do that:

```
Map<List<Item>, Double> items = new HashMap<>();

List<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>> list = new ArrayList<>(items.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(
          Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double> o1,
          Map.Entry<List<Item>, Double> o2) {
          return Integer.compare(o2.getKey().size(), o1.getKey().size());
        }
    }

});
```

If you need a `TreeSet` or a `TreeMap`, then the use of a `Comparator` is fine but **you have to define what happens when the lists size are equals**: you need to use another criteria to determine ordering (like comparing each items a, b of both list, until `a.compareTo(b) != 0`).